# Dictionary values are overwritng instead of adding into the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

The data structure I need to achieve is:

```
{
    '179': {
        'name': [ < object > , < object > , < object > ],
        'lastname': [ < object > , object > , < object > ]
    }
}
```

And I have the following code to achieve it:

```
if g_id in email_data:
    email_data[g_id]['name'] = names
    email_data[g_id]['lastname'] = lastnames
else:
    email_data[g_id] = {'name': names}
    email_data[g_id] = {'lastname': lastnames}
print email_data
```

But some how I can't achieve it. The last data `lastname` is always appending like `{'179': {'lastname': [<object>, <object>, <object>]}}`, but the `name` is missing. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not `email_data[g_id] = {'name':  names, 'lastname':  lastnames}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change:

```
    else:
        email_data[g_id] = {'name':  names}
        email_data[g_id] = {'lastname':  lastnames}
```

To:

```
    else:
        email_data[g_id] = {'name':  names, 'lastname':  lastnames}
```

Otherwise you are overwriting `email_data[g_id]`.

Think about:

```
    else:
        a = 1
        a = 2
```

What is the value of `a`?

Answer (score 1):

In the `else` block, you should *update* the dictionary not *reassign*:

```
email_data[g_id] = {'name':  names}
email_data[g_id].update({'lastname':  lastnames})
```

Or simply *assign* all the keys/values at once:

```
email_data[g_id] = {'name': names, 'lastname': lastnames}
```